# XCode 12.0.1 and 12.1 Do not build universal applications

Tags: macos, arm, macos-catalina, xcode12

Using XCode 12.0.1 or 12.1 on MacOS 10.15.7 on a MacBook Pro, I cannot get my Mac OS application to compile for the arm64 architecture (i.e. make a Universal application).  My project has evolved through many many many XCode versions, so I thought maybe it was corrupted somehow.

So, I created a new non-document-based app project in XCode.  I then edited the scheme for Run to build for Release.  The default build settings included the arm64 archtecture, and "Build Active Archtecture Only" set to NO for Release.  I then set the tool bar scheme setting to buid for "Any Mac", built the project and looked at the build log. It built only for the x86_64 architecture.

Apple's documentaton says it should build for both architectures with these settings.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Apple's documentation, whoch clearly says XCode 12 builds universal.  It does not, as of this writing, you MUST use the xcode 12 BETA.

Comment: This is true. My macOS projects do not compile for arm64 with Xcode 12.1, but they do with Xcode 12.2 beta 4 (Release Candidate)

Comment: Oh, geez.  I wasted a bunch of time trying to figure this out.  Aargh.  Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've had older Xcode-Projects that just wouldn't build universal binaries. It was due to a VALID_ARCHS user defined variable in one of the build settings (at the very bottom of the list). Once removed, universal binaries were created.